# Display child window on fixed position in MFC CScrollView

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a window inherited from CScrollView that handles WM_PAINT and displays a graph. This graph has elements of different types and type of element is marked by the shape of element.

I want to display some legend so that user knows what each shape means. Since user will not look at this legend often the idea is that in the upper right corner of the view control there will be a small icon. When user moves the mouse over this icon it will expand into small rectangle displaying the legend of shapes used in graph. When mouse is moved outside this rectangle it will collapse back to small icon.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Draw the hotspot icon and legend rectangle using GDI in handler of WM_PAINT of view class.
2. Implement hotspot as a separate window that is created as a child of a scroll view.
3. Implement hotspot as a separate window but create it as a popup window with no parent.

Version 1 and 2 behave strangely if user scrolls the graph view.

In version 1 I can see artifacts (button is smeared across the view) while performing scroll I guess that during the scroll existing image is not invalidated but only moved.

In version 2 there is no smearing but I need to move the child window whenever I get VM_HSCROLL and WM_VSCROLL messages and these messages are not precise enough to be used this way. During scroll I can see my button moving couple of pixels and then jumping to correct position.

Version 3 is the most disturbing and because legend is not child of a graph view I get some strange behaviour where legend button is displayed even when graph view is not shown and I think that there are too many problems with this one to be viable development path to invest time in.

I think that the version 2 is the most promising but I need to find a way to make a child window stay at one place during scroll.

Did anyone have success in implementing something like this? Is there some other implementation I can investigate?

Answer (score 1):

`CScrollView` has `OnScrollBy` virtual method that scrolls the entire client area of view control. You can override this method and implement your own scroll functionality.

[`::ScrollWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a parameter `prcScroll` that can specify only a portion of client area that will be scrolled.

New `OnScrollBy` splits client area into 4 stripes and calls `::ScrollWindowEx` for each one of them.

These stripes are:

1. client area above icon (rectangle width across entire client area)
2. client area on the left of icon (rectangle height same as icon)
3. client area on the right of icon (rectangle height same as icon)
4. client area underneath icon (rectangle width across entire client area)

   1 1 1 1 1
   2 2 2 * 3
   4 4 4 4 4
   4 4 4 4 4

After scrolling all individual client rectangles, just invalidate client area where icon is located.

Comment: A simpler solution would probably work as well: In your `OnScrollBy` override you can `::ScrollWindowEx` the entire client area and then invalidate the rectangle where the icon is located plus the area above/below or to the left/right of it, depending on scroll direction and distance.

Comment: Actually IInspectable, yours is the correct answer. My over engineering leads to some problems with order of ::ScrollWindowEx calls. If windows is scrolled upwards, then scroll should be done in this order: 1, 2, 3, 4. But if window is scrolled downward scroll should be done in this order: 4, 3, 2, 1. Can you post separate reply so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You may just simply use

```
CPoint GetScrollPosition( ) const;
```

method to obtain current scroll position of scroll view and recalculate your 'static' label offset accordingly.

BTW: Instead of WM_PAINT use CScrollView's method

```
virtual void OnDraw( CDC* pDC );
```

it's important

Comment: `OnDraw` **is** the `WM_PAINT` handler.

Comment: IInspectable, you will remember OnDraw when go work with Printer DC. Especially for CSCrollView :)

Comment: Wow... I have no clue what you were trying to say here. Whether `OnDraw` is passed a paint DC, a window DC, a printer DC, or a meta DC is completely irrelevant to my comment that `OnDraw` **is** the `WM_PAINT` handler. So if you say "Use X (which is invoked when Y happens), instead of calling X in response to Y" suggests that you are lacking basic insight into MFC.

Comment: so, why do you think Microsoft exposed OnDraw method in CView instead of tell people use WM_PAINT directly? My opinion is better use standard MFC way to do this and back to WinAPI when it is really needed.

Comment: Microsoft provides `OnDraw` for the same reason C++ provides `std::string`: Convenience and safety. The point is, there is no difference between calling `strlen` and `std::string::size()` or between overriding `OnDraw` and handling `WM_PAINT`. If you disagree, read the source code.

Comment: You have provided not good example because strlen is not always equal std::string::size(). Seems you are lacking knowlege in stl

Comment: As with all analogies they are dangerous territory. Yes, `std::string`s can contain embedded `NUL` characters. Big deal. By the same token you can also totally fail to handle `WM_PAINT` correctly. Point still stands: You recommend to use something else, which is entirely the same thing. If you didn't waste this much time and gained some reputation instead this could be continued in a chat instead of flooding this platform with useless conversation.

Comment: @IInspectable OnDraw and WM_PAINT are not the same. OnDraw happens AFTER the DC has been setup, which in a CScrollView is important because it's setting up its viewports. Look at CScrollView::OnPrepareDC for more info.

Comment: @snowdude That's what I described as *convenience* above. Setting up a viewport is convenient, but by no means a requirement. Regardless of all this, it has nothing to do with the question asked by the poster. He is well aware of how a `CScrollView` works. This answer does not attempt to address the question at all.